# Twilio Incoming Call - asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

I'm building an asp.net c# website and using Twilio.  I'm working on getting it to answer an incoming call but it's not working, every time I call it says there's an application error.

This is what I have in the .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="callTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="callTest" %><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

This is what I have in the aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.TwiML;

public partial class callTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var twiml = new Twilio.TwiML.TwilioResponse();
        twiml.Say("Hello Monkey!");

        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        Response.Write(twiml.ToString());
        Response.Close();
    }
}
```

If I comment out the c# code above and put the following in the .aspx file, it works fine, do you guys know what I'm doing wrong with my c# code?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="callTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="callTest" %><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Say>If you are calling from a house phone, press one.</Say>
    <Gather/>
</Response>
```

Comment: What IS the application error?

Comment: It literally just says, "We're sorry, an application error has occurred, goodbye."

Comment: returned the HTTP status code 502. Please check the URL and try again.

<html><head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head><body><h1>Bad Gateway</h1>An upstream server returned an invalid response.</body></html>

Comment: Sounds like something is blocking the request.

Answer (score 1):

The reason Twilio is reporting an application error is because there is no XML returned by your page.  And, the reason there is no XML returned by your page is quite simply because of the Response.Close() call.  Replace the Response.Close() call with Response.End();.  Response.End() sends all currently buffered output to the client, while Response.Close() closes the socket connection to the client.

TL;DR;
Replace
`Response.Close();`
with
`Response.End();`

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Try testing this web page by loading the URL you've set as the Voice URL in a browser.  Can you reach it successfully and get the TwiML as you would expect?

Twilio is basically telling you "hey, I tried to request this URL but something between me and you made that fail".

That something could be a firewall, a proxy server, etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have it hosted on smarterasp.net and my Twilio SMS send and receive pages work without a hitch.  When I load the page in a browser it is a blank page.  Pretty much everything is in the aspx.cs file, am I missing anything from the aspx file?

Comment: Its hard to tell.  You code looks correct, but if the response is empty then it seems like something is not working right.  Did you make sure to check the source?  You might also use a tool like Fiddler to be able to look at the raw HTTP request your making and make sure the ContentType header is being set properly.  An incorrect ContentType header could cause the 502 error.